# odd even numbers alternate inverted triangle

Tags: java

I want to print the following pattern in java:

```
a+1357+1
b+246+2
a+13+3
b+2+4
```

following is my code, but with this i can only print odd no. or only even no.s

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 7;
    for(int i = rows; i >= 1; i=i-2) {
       for(int j = 1; j <= i; j=j+2) {
           System.out.print(j + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are a and b?

Comment: please, explain the pattern in more detail - does 'a' stand for odd and 'b' for even numbers? is the trailing number a line counter? how many digits should be in the middle part and why? should the result look exactly like in your output example (exactly four rows, exactly same content) or should different input render different results with similar pattern and according to what logic?

Answer (score 2):

With only a few updates of your code (but not very readable):

```
    int rows = 7;
    for (int i = rows; i >= 1; i = i - 2) {
        System.out.print((((i + 1) % 4) == 0 ? "a" : "b") + " + ");
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j = j + 2) {
            System.out.print((j + ((i + 2) % 4) / 2));
        }
        System.out.println(" + " + (10 - i) / 2);
    }
```

But instead of using my code, I suggest you write down exactly how the "pattern" is defined and write new code based on your specification. These loops are not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO**

```js
var rows = 4;
for (var i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    document.write((i % 2) + (2 * j) - 1 + " ");
  }
  document.write('<br>');
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int rows = 4;
   for(int i = rows; i > 0; i--) {
      for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          System.out.print((i%2)+(2*j)-1 + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

You need to make a pattern for it. here you can use `(i%2)+(2*j)-1`